# Different Jobrepository datasource per job in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

If I have 2 jobs, each of which writes to a different datasource, it would make sense to write the spring batch metadata (jobExecution, results, ...) in the datasource which it worked with. However spring batch seems to direct you to have one "primary" datasource to use for that metadata.

I defined two datasources, neither is marked as primary, and the application fails to start:

```
Field dataSource in org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - firstDataSource: defined by method 'firstDataSource' in class path resource [secret/DataSourceConfig.class]
    - secondDataSource: defined by method 'secondDataSource' in class path resource [secret/DataSourceConfig.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

I tried to create two configurations that each extend DefaultBatchConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job my_job(@Qualifier("somestep") Step step) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("my_job")
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("my_job")
    public JobExecution launchMyJob(@Qualifier("my_job") Job job, JobLauncher jobLauncher) throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        Map<String, JobParameter> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("Time", new JobParameter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())));
        return jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters(params));
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(@Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
}
```

The other one is exactly the same only different job and datasource.

So why does spring still try to create a AbstractBatchConfiguration when clearly I want to do this myself by extending DefaultBatchConfigurer?

More stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: firstDataSource,secondDataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean using multiple datasource in your project?

Here is a example for you reference

https://github.com/michaelliao/springcloud/tree/master/data-multidatasource

Comment: No, I am already using multiple datasources. The question is to configure two datasources for spring batch metadata, each one for their respective jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch's `SimpleBatchConfiguration` is brought in via the `@EnableBatchProcessing`.  That uses the `BatchConfigurer` to provide the components it needs to add to the `ApplicationContext`.  What you really want to do is create a `BatchConfigurer` that provides the right `DataSource` at the right time.  Then the `SimpleBatchConfiguration` will use the components created by your configurer to add them to the `ApplicationContext`.